# modifier that creates linear texture wrapping? multiple 3d models

Tags: three.js, textures, modifier, texture-wrapping

So I have two 3d models with different geometry so when the textures are applied they wrap differently, leaving the textures looking funny and uneven. I was wondering if there was a modifier that could change how the texture is applied?

EXAMPLE:

3dmax has a modifier called MAP_SCALER, you can add it to any model that has a lot of vertices, faces and it still displays the texture in a seamless and linear fashion. If anyone can help!! my mind will surely be blown!! I need this resolved ASAP!